# Is there a way to lock one record before starting to modify that record?

Tags: c#, ado.net, firebird, firebird-embedded

Is there a way to lock one record before starting to modify that record?

```
string stOpenConn = new FbConnectionStringBuilder {
    Database = stPathFilename,
    UserID = stUserID,
    Password = stPassword,
    ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded,
    ClientLibrary = stCLIENT_LIBRARY
}.ToString();

try {
    using(FbConnection fbConn = new FbConnection(stOpenConn)) {
        fbConn.Open();

        string stCmd = "UPDATE " + stTableName + " SET " + liststFieldNamesNoKeyID[0] + " = @p0";
        for (int iii = 1; iii < liststFieldNamesNoKeyID.Count(); iii++)
            stCmd += ", " + liststFieldNamesNoKeyID[iii] + " = @p" + iii.ToString();
        stCmd += " WHERE" + stFieldKeyID + "= @p" + liststFieldNamesNoKeyID.Count().ToString();

        FbTransaction fbTransaction = fbConn.BeginTransaction();
        using (FbCommand fbCmd = new FbCommand(stCmd, fbConn, fbTransaction)) {
            for (int iii = 0; iii < liststFieldNamesNoKeyID.Count(); iii++) {
                string stPlaceHolder = "@p" + (iii).ToString();
                string stValue = liststNewValuesNoKeyID[iii];
                fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(stPlaceHolder, stValue);
            }
            int iKeyID = Convert.ToInt32(stKeyID);
            fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p" + liststFieldNamesNoKeyID.Count().ToString(), iKeyID);
            fbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            fbTransaction.Commit();
        }//using
    }//using
}//try
```

And then releasing after modification is complete?

I presume that the record lock occurs after the connection is open ... before the BeginTransaction ... and releasing the record lock after the fbTransaction.Commit.

Comment: That is what transactions are for. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The purpose is to keep two people from changing the same record simultaneously.  Based on your comment, Mark Rotteveel, it appears that transactions lock the record.  I had performed an Internet search prior to this post ... saw nothing that tied transactions to locking a record. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: If you update, then another transaction cannot update that same record, while the first transaction has not been committed.

Comment: This depends on the isolation level for the transaction.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras In Firebird, trying to update a record that was already updated by another - still active - transaction will result in an update conflict, what depends on the transaction isolation is whether you are allowed to update the record after that transaction has committed.

Comment: Is there a flag that lets the code know when a transaction is in process by another user?  Perhaps one that is similar to a try / catch?

Comment: Use a no-wait transaction (or a wait transaction with a timeout), and you get an exception if you try to modify a record that is already modified by another transaction.

Comment: A search provides few "wait" / "no wait" details.  It appears that a FbTransactionOptions and TransactionBehavior may work. ----- FbTransaction fbTransaction = fbConn.BeginTransaction(); new FbTransactionOptions() { TransactionBehavior = FbTransactionBehavior.Concurrency | FbTransactionBehavior.Wait }; 
-----  Is there a website that provides more details, along with an example?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you want to do that, you may use (with care) the `WITH LOCK` clause of a select, which will turn into a pessimistic lock (that's why you need to be cautious when using it). More information can be found in the documentation of [`WITH LOCK`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-dml.html#fblangref40-dml-with-lock). A "dumb" update will also act as a pessimistic lock.